# pointer or return two values to print

Tags: c, return-value, precision, key-value-store

I'm trying to write function which get 2 values or return one value . So when i want use function i got values which are addresses i think

```
int function (int a, int *b, *c){
    int value;
    value=a*2; 
    (*b)=value/10;
    (*c)=value%10;
}

int main(void){
    int val1,p1,p2,rest1,rest2;
    val1=150;
    function(val1,&p1,&p2);
    rest1=p1*2+p2;
    rest2=p2;
    printf("%d m %d end %d"rest1,rest2,&p2);
}
```

also i think about return only one

```
int funct2(int a){
    int array [2];
    int b=(65*a)/100;
    int c=b%1000;
    array[0]=b;
    array[1]=c;
    return array;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a=18;
    int array[2];
    array=funct2(a);
}
```

Doesn't work either.

So how can i buld function to get 2 values or get this 2 values as one value.. please help

Comment: Your first example looks pretty close, what's the problem?  Your second example won't work - you can't return an array like that.

Comment: values which i get from first function are to high, ex i should got  values from b = 1 and from c =5690 but i got to high numbers ex b 695922 and c 265488. what's more, every time when i run the program i got different values..

Comment: Go with your first solution and check out hmjd's answer. You don't need the & in the printf since, at that point, you're in main. p2 is a local variable there. You only need the & to pass the address of p2 to function().

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect:

```
printf("%d m %d end %d",rest1,rest2,&p2);
```

as the last argument, `&p2`, is an `int*` (the address of `p2`) but the format specifier is a `%d`. Change to:

```
printf("%d m %d end %d", rest1, rest2, p2);
```

To return two `int`s you could define a `struct` and return by value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct int_pair
{
    int division_result, modulus_result;
};

struct int_pair function (const int a)
{
    const int value = a * 2;
    struct int_pair result;

    result.division_result = value / 10;
    result.modulus_result  = value % 10;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    struct int_pair p = function(150);
    printf("%d %d\n", p.division_result, p.modulus_result);
    return 0;
}
```

If C99 the `function()` could use compound literal for return value:

```
struct int_pair function (const int a)
{
    const int value = a * 2;
    return (struct int_pair) { value / 10, value % 10 };
}
```

See http://ideone.com/8PFtHq for demo.

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt to return multiple values,

```
int funct2(int a){
int array [2];
int b=(65*a)/100;
int c=b%1000;
array[0]=b;
array[1]=c;
return array;
}
```

You are returning a local variable which is *undefined behaviour*, meaning the program is no longer considered to be valid.

Simply pass an array from `main` and changes will propagate back to main.

Your function declaration would like this:

```
void funct2(int *a, int size){ //size is the number of elements
```

Call from main() would like this:

```
int a[2];
func(a, 2);
```

Comment: it still doesn't work, i exactly don't know how use your tip.

Comment: @Matt It does. May be, you didn't implement it correctly. A simple example here: http://ideone.com/gv4xAi

Answer (score 0):

First function fixed :

```
void function1 (int a, int *b, int *c){
    int value;
    value=a*2;
    (*b)=value/10;
    (*c)=value%10;
}

int main(void){
    int val1,p1,p2,rest1,rest2;
    val1=150;
    function1(val1,&p1,&p2);
    rest1=p1*2+p2;
    rest2=p2;
    printf("%d m %d end %d\r\n",rest1,rest2,&p2);
}
```

Second function fixed :

```
int* function2(int a){
    int* array = (int*)malloc(2);
    int b=(65*a)/100;
    int c=b%1000;
    array[0]=b;
    array[1]=c;
    return array;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a=18;
    int* array;
    array=function2(a);

    //You can access array[0] and array[1]
    //...

    free(array);
}
```